# TFS Through Load Balancer - Login Prompts

Tags: amazon-web-services, tfs, amazon-elb

We have set up a TFS 2012 Server on AWS and have implemented one of the newer Application Load Balancers in front of it.  We did this to leverage the CName functionality and save on our Elastic IP Address allocation.  This server is only for the internal team, but we were creating a public URL.

When logging into the server directly through the local IP, it prompts for un/password one time, when coming from external through the load balancer, every AJAX call gets prompted on the page, and you end up with numerous prompts.  It seems to be a problem with the pass through authentication of the site.  We've tried adjusting numerous things, and read several articles on how to configure TFS, but still can't figure out what setting we're missing.

Does this need to switch to a Classic?  We are at the cap on our Elastic IPs, and I'd rather not request an extra, but if that's the only way I will.  Any insight or items to check would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just checking: you do know that requesting an increase in the number of elastic IP addresses you're allowed to allocate is a simple process and has no associated cost, right?

Comment: Yes, just trying to be a good steward of the IPv4 space.

Comment: Fair enough. I support that motivation, absolutely. The only problem is that ELBs are typically auto-assigned at least *two* public IPv4 addresses, not just one... so, that's a bit counterproductive to this end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're using Elastic Load Balancer with "Windows Authentication", you need to configure your ELB's listener for "TCP", not "HTTP" or "HTTPS". Basically, ELB changes the authentication information that Windows does not like.

At this time, ALB cannot use "TCP" listeners.

Try using a classic ELB with a "TCP" listener instead.

Comment: Going to try this - will report back, but this makes good sense.