# Preventing multiple user/password prompts when using Windows authentication (NTLM) on IIS behind an ALB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, windows-authentication

I am trying to setup Windows authentication for my asp.net core 2.2 app running on an IIS 10 server (on Windows Server 2019). However, I do NOT want to use Integrated or automatic authentication, the site is available from the public internet, therefore I want users to login via fixed user accounts created on the IIS server (needs user/password prompts).

What I tried until now is to setup the website, with all the permission management in place, the website is callable and a popup is shown when calling the site asking for username and password. 
However, when loading the website over a public domain the user/password prompt opens up repeatedly, even though providing the correct credentials. 
When looking at the developer console I can see that resources are loaded in different steps, external libraries are loaded subsequently, and for each load the user has to authenticate again. 
The goal is to have the user/password prompt display only once, and have all subsequently loaded resources from the website already authenticated. I tried it with another sample .net core app as well, which works just fine.

I am a C# newbie and the application has been written by a colleague. I noticed some directives in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js" asp-append-version="true" integrity="sha384-<hash>"></script>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js" asp-append-version="true" integrity="sha384-<hash>"></script>
</environment>
```

Also at the end of the page a `Scripts` section is loaded dynamically:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Is it possible that the dynamic loading of scripts or setting of environments could cause libraries to be loaded asynchronously, and therefore need to be re-authenticated?

The IIS server runs on AWS behind an application load balancer setup with different paths pointing to different websites on the IIS server. A public domain redirects to the ALB. The user calls the public domain including a sub-path (e.g. `https://cloud.domain/path`) and is redirected to the appropriate Website.

I would really appreciate feedback, as the authentication mechanism is not feasible as it is now. When switching to Basic authentication everything works fine, the user is authenticated exactly once and all subsequent calls are made automatically. But of course, basic authentication does not meet the security requirements, therefore windows authentication should be used.

Comment: It seems though that the problem is more related to the routing via the public domain and AWS load balancer. When calling the IIS server instance directly via its private IP the authentication problem does not occur. I will further investigate this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I figured that Windows Authentication does not work over https, it needs a tcp connection. 
Since Application Load Balancers on AWS only allow http and https there are complications with this approach. However, Network Load Balancers operate on TCP and therefore work nicely with Windows Authentication.

Here are some references I found to this topic:

[tfs-through-load-balancer-login-prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000562/tfs-through-load-balancer-login-prompts)

[windows_authentication_with_application_load](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/97w0qz/windows_authentication_with_application_load/)

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, but HTTP and HTTPS are protocols over the top of a TCP connection, so that can't be the issue.

It could be that the application load balancer is not passing the authentication on for some reason because it does a lot more than just "forward packets", but is has nothing to do with the use of a TCP connection.

Comment: That is right, HTTP and HTTPS both operate commonly via TCP (could be UDP as well), however on AWS it is handled differently. 
I guess that as you said some authentication settings are not passed when using an ALB via HTTP or HTTPS, as there are some restrictions. Only via the NLB this is currently possible

Comment: No it could not be UDP.  

HTTP/HTTPS are require a connection.  UDP is a connectionless protocol that does not support guaranteed delivery and retransmission. UDP applications have to allow for missing data and handle it themselves.